# Similar function to R's logsum function (mlogit package) for Survival package

Tags: r, mlogit

I was trying to obtain the expected utility for each individual using R's `survival` package (`clogit` function) and I was not able to find a simple solution such as mlogit's `logsum`.

Below I set an example of how one would do it using the `mlogit` package. It is pretty straight forward: it just requires regressing the variables with the `mlogit` function, save the output and use it as an argument in the `logsum` function -- if needed, there is a short explanation in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/c3.rum.html). And what I want is to know the similar method for `clogit`. I've read the package's [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf) but I have failed to grasp what would be the most adequate function to perform the analsysis.

Note1: My preference for a function like `mlogit's` is related to the fact that I might need to perform tons of regressions later on and being able to perform the correct estimation in different scenarios would be helpful.

Note2: I do not intend that the dataset created below be representative of how data should behave. I've set the example solely for the purpose of perfoming the function after the logit regressions.

**

```
library(survival)
library(mlogit)

#creating a dataset

df_test=data.frame(id=rep(1:20,each=4),
                   choice=rep(c("train","car","plane","boat")),
                   distance=c(rnorm(80)*10),
                   )

f=function(x,y,z) {
    
  v=round(rnorm(x,y,z))
    
    while(sum(v)>1 | sum(v)==0) {
      
      v=round(rnorm(x,y,z))
      
    }
  
return(v)
    
}

result1=c()

for (i in 1:20) {
  
  result=f(4,0.5,0.1)
  
  result1=c(result,result1)
  
}

df_test$distance=ifelse(df_test$distance<0,df_test$distance*-1,df_test$distance)
df_test$price = 0
df_test$price[df_test$choice=="plane"] = rnorm(20, mean = 300, sd=30)
df_test$price[df_test$choice=="car"] = rnorm(20, mean = 50, sd=10)
df_test$price[df_test$choice=="boat"] = rnorm(20, mean = 100, sd=15)
df_test$price[df_test$choice=="train"] = rnorm(20, mean = 120, sd=25)

df_test$choice2=result1
           
mlog=mlogit(choice2 ~ distance + price , data = df_test)

#the function logsum generates expected utility for each individual

logsum(mlog)

#so what would be adequate alternative with survival's clogit? I set an exemple below of
#of what i would like to regress and then perform something like logsum()

clog=clogit(choice2 ~ distance + price + as.factor(choice), strata(id), data = df_test)
```

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vignette you offer says the logsum is calculated as:

[image]

To my reading that is similar to the calculation used to construct the "linear predictor". the lp is `t(coef(clog)) %*% Xhat`. If I'm correct on that interpretation, then that is stored in the `clog`-object:

```
 clog["linear.predictor"]
```

So you could just take:

```
log(sum( exp(clog[["linear.predictors"]]) ))
[1] 4.286592
```

If you need to segregate this by `df_test$choice` then (since the length of the 'linear.predictors' element of `clog` is the same as the length of the 'choice' column of `df_test`) it's just:`

```
 tapply(clog$linear.predictors, df_test$choice, function(x){ 
               log(sum( exp(x) ))})
 #--------------------------------------
    boat      car    plane    train 
2.824502 3.506756 2.825004 1.734258
```

If you need to aggregate this by `id`, you would do it like this:

```
tapply(clog$linear.predictors, df_test$id, function(x){ 
  log(sum( exp(x) ))})

       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9 
1.405896 1.506152 1.454507 1.539060 1.467082 1.428482 1.393582 1.521877 1.480670 
      10       11       12       13       14       15       16       17       18 
1.466490 1.416338 1.500581 1.528075 1.488253 1.398405 1.445014 1.483623 1.404041 
      19       20 
1.460672 1.452709
```

Comment: I think you're partially correct. But we need to index this to each id - each 'iv' has an 'i'.

Comment: OK. Eazy-peezy. See above.

Comment: I will award you the bounty, but you need sum the values of each choice by each ID -- the index J refers to choices, the 'i' to the IDs of the individuals. What I meant is that you need to provide a 'logsum' of each ID.

Comment: could you please show how you would get the linear predictors as in `t(coef(clog)) %*% Xhat`? I've haven't been able to obtain the value with the estimated coefficients.

Comment: I think you might not be taking into account the conditional structure on the calculations.

Comment: If you could just provide a reference on how the linear predictors are calculated, that would be great :) I was trying find out how the `lp` option is calculated with the `predict` function, but that is still not clear to me.

Comment: But still. I will award you the bounty if you just correct your function to sum the value through each individual - if the `lp` option is indeed correct. 

One possible way to this -- and using only the `clogit` object -- might be to get the length of the `xlevels`, divide by `dim(df_teste)[1]` and recreate the ID. 

Also, if I am not mistaken, there is no way to get the original dataset stored in the object created by `clogit`. Right?

Comment: `?clogit`:"It turns out that the loglikelihood for a cond. logistic regression model = loglik from a Cox model with a particular data structure. Proving this is a nice homework exercise for a PhD statistics class; not too hard, but the fact that it is true is surprising.

[snipped one sentence]  In detail, a stratified Cox model with each c-c group assigned to its own stratum, time set to a constant, status of 1=case 0=control,.."  and then 2 references are given.

Comment: To your request for a calculation with both choice and id grouping, that would lead to an 80 cell table for a dataset with 80 cases and there would be exactly 1 linear predictor per cell, so summation would be redundant.

Comment: Not to group by choice. Just ID. That is what the `logsum` function provides for the `mlogit` object.

Comment: Do you think we could do this solely with the information produced by the `clogit` object (`clog`) and not using the dataset of the data.frame? Such as not using `df_test$id`, but something that is stored in the `clog` object.

Comment: I didn’t see sufficient information. The Surv object was the but not the pairing details. The coxph function allows storage of both the x and y components but not clog it.